# Run A Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to run a stored procedure on each ID return by a `SELECT` query. Is there a simple way to do something like:

```
FOREACH (SELECT ID FROM myTABLE WHERE myName='bob') AS id
BEGIN
    EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[spMYPROC]
         @PARAM1 = id
         @PARAM2 = 0
END
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do some sort of looping on a table, why not pass in the ID's to the stored procedure?

Comment: Agreed with @TTeeple - change the stored procedure to handle all of the rows in `myTABLE` instead of a singleton procedure that you call N times. There is significant overhead in looping at all, never mind calling a stored procedure every time. SQL Server is optimized to work on sets. You want to do something in your procedure to every row in a set, but you really should change it to just do whatever that is to all the rows at once. If you show the body of your procedure we can help you do that.

Comment: Check out this post, it does something very similar: [Run a Stored Procedure multiple times dynamicly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333405/run-a-stored-procedure-multiple-times-dynamicly/21335138#21335138)

Comment: I do think a set based approach would serve you better.

Comment: The T-SQL command for looping is `while`, not `foreach` (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx).  If your stored procedure is designed to take one `id`, I wouldn't recommend changing it to take many ids, unless that is a reasonable requirement for the API.

Comment: @Gordon Oh, I have to disagree there. You can keep this singleton stored procedure for the API if it is impossible to change, but you absolutely should create a different stored procedure that deals with a set if that's the case. TVPs are very easy to switch to, and I really don't think a while loop or a cursor is the best way to handle the above. Imagine if thousands of rows meet that where clause; ouch.

Comment: The suggestion to modify it to take a set of IDs makes sense as long as the stored procedure makes sense to be modified in this way. In my case, the stored procedure is currently only used internally (by me, specifically) so I think changing it to accept a set of IDs is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I don't disagree with your suggestion of creating another stored procedure, just with modifying the existing one.  Even so, the OP will still need to learn about `while` or something similar; that just moves the question down one level.

Comment: @Gordon not necessarily. We don't know what the stored procedure does and if it really has to deal with one row at a time. Maybe it can perform a single operation against myTable instead of operating on each value individually, and maybe it can take `'bob'` as an argument instead of fussing with one or multiple ids in the first place. This is why I asked for the body of the procedure.

Comment: @Gordon sorry to reply to you here, it was my last response from you, I just don't know how long it takes for you to get a ping about comment responses on mssqltips. Wanted to warn you to grab a coffee or two before [reading my response about MERGE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement).

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Thank you for taking the time to answer.  You know that I respect your positions on these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since I just happened to answer a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333405/run-a-stored-procedure-multiple-times-dynamically/21335138#21335138) yesterday, I have this code handy. As others have stated, it may not be the best approach, but still it's nice to learn how to use a while loop anyway.

Assuming a table named "Customer"

```
declare @Id int

select @Id = MIN(Id)
from Customer c


while(select COUNT(1)
      from Customer c
      where c.Id >= @Id) > 0
    begin

        --run your sproc right here

        select @Id = MIN(Id)
        from Customer c
        where c.Id > @Id


    end
```

Comment: interesting one served my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You have two option here

**Option 1 Using Split Function**

Pass a comma deliminated list of IDs and use a Split function Inside your Procedure to make split these values and do whatever you want to do with it.

> To
>   Make it work you will need two thing
>
> 1) Create a Function which
>   accepts a  Comma Deliminated string and split them.
>
> 2) Modify you
>   Store Procedure and add this function in there in a way that passed
>   parameter is passed to the function inside that store procedure and
>   that function split the values before passing it onto your store
>   Procedure .

Create this function 1st

**Function Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (Id int identity(1,1), Value nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN

WHILE(Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)

  BEGIN


        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)

        SELECT VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))

  END


INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)

SELECT VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

RETURN

END
```

**Modify you strored Procedure something like this**

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER Procedure  [dbo].[spMYPROC] (@Param1 VARCHAR(1000)= NULL)
AS
BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM TableName
        where ColumnNAME  IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Param1,','))

END
GO
```

**Option 2 Table Type Parameter**

Create a Table Type and alter your proc to accept a Table Type Parameter and do whatever you want to do with them values inside your proc.

**TABLE TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TYPENAME AS TABLE 
 (
    Value int 
  )
 GO
```

**Stored Procedure to Accept That Type Param**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMYPROC]  
 @TableParam TYPENAME READONLY
 AS 
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  --Temp table to store passed Id values
  declare @tmp_values table (value INT );   

   --Insert passed values to a table variable inside the proc

   INSERT INTO @tmp_values (value)
   SELECT Value FROM @TableParam

    /* Do your stuff here whatever you want to do with Ids */

END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

Declare a variable of that type and populate it with your values.

```
 DECLARE @Table TYPENAME     --<-- Variable of this TYPE

 INSERT INTO @Table                --<-- Populating the variable 
 SELECT ID FROM myTABLE WHERE myName='bob'

EXECUTE [dbo].[spMYPROC]  @Table   --<-- Stored Procedure Executed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ID INT, @return_value INT

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    ID
FROM myTABLE
WHERE myName = 'bob'

OPEN c; FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[spMYPROC]
         @PARAM1 = @ID,
         @PARAM2 = 0

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID
END

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```